# Combine string[] to string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Is there a quick way to pack an array of strings to a string? 
More specifically,I have an array of strings like this:
string[] Operators = {"+","-","x","/"} and I would like to pack it to
string sOperators = "+-x/"
Of course, the obvious way is to read each item in the array and put it in the string individually, but is there a better way that people smarter than me can think of?
I have tried:

```
string sOperators="";
String.Join(sOperators,Operators);
```

Unfortunately, that won't work for me. Any thought?

Comment: `string.Join` is the right thing to use here - what exactly do you mean by "it won't work"?

Comment: Wait, you're assigning the result of `String.Join` to a variable, right?

Comment: Please [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx). If you had and looked at *any* of the examples, you'd see that you're not using it correctly.

Comment: @s.m. I did not and I should. My bad. Thank you for pointing it out. As soon as I assign it back to sOperators, I got the string. Thank you!

Comment: @user1205746 you're welcome. Take a moment to read about how strings work in the .NET framework. They are immutable, among other things, which entails some peculiarities, but discovering what they are is left as an exercise for the willing learner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code sample could just be incomplete but based on you've posted the problem is that you're not assigning the joined string anywhere. I think the following will do what you want;

```
 string joined = String.Join(sOperators, Operators);
```

Join returns a new string, it does not make any changes to the arguments you pass it. You need to assign the return value to some field, property, constant, or variable in order to produce the desired result.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to assign it back to the string. Silly mistake!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.Concat(Operators)` (MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9c94ey1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use String.Join for this:

```
string sOperators = string.Join("", Operators);
```

I guess you just forgot to assign the result to a variable.

Comment: @QtX Misuses rather than uses. Or do you believe that this code does not do what is required?

Comment: a) You answered without reading the question, b) a  very simple answer to very simple question should be complete(without syntax errors) 3) you are late.

Comment: @qtx I read the question fine. I made a mistake (thanks to ruddy android auto correct) which I fixed. Why does speed matter? The best answer is the fastest one?

Comment: Why do you insist on this answer? it is not better then the fastest one. do you really need these a few reps :) I would upvote the other answer and delete mine.

Comment: Thanks, David. I forgot to assign it back to the variable. I should have known better. Rookie mistake happened after 8 hours starring at the screen.. :)